# about google maps + jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I found a tutorial about google maps using jquery. When I read the API documentation, they uses `API_KEY`, but the tutorial shows something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
```

what is the difference? the documentation uses

```
"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY">
```

can someone explain me about this? I'm very new to maps by the way.

Comment: Google does not make use of API keys necessary, but it's good to have if you want to track your map usage by visitors: "Using an API key enables you to monitor your application's Maps API usage, and ensures that Google can contact you about your application if necessary." [Source](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key).

Comment: I see. thanks a lot for the explanation. more power. @Terry

Answer (score 0):

To create your API key:

Visit the Google Developers Console and log in with your Google Account.
Click the Services link from the left-hand menu.
Activate the Google Maps JavaScript API v3 service.
Click the API Access link from the left-hand menu. Your API key is available from the API Access page, in the Simple API Access section. Maps API applications use the Key for browser apps.

By default, a key can be used on any site. We strongly recommend that you restrict the use of your key to domains that you administer, to prevent use on unauthorized sites. You can specify which domains are allowed to use your API key by clicking the Edit allowed referrers... link for your key.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Google Map Version 3 don't required the API Key. and this tutorial is based on Google map Version 3. And the Google Map Version 2 require the API key. for more detail check this...

http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2010/03/introducing-new-google-geocoding-web.html